# Repeated vector of zeros showing up in my READ_MESSAGE thread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm really confused why I'm having an unexpected array of 0000 while I'm pressing on the sensor (A circuit that converts A/D. Digital data starts from 0000 to 1024 depending on pressure from the sensor). The digital adapter should send whatever is coming in from the pressure sensor.

I would like to attach some of my `MainActivity` code. I think the problem is something in READ_MESSAGE case inside handler. It is also slowing down my graph once the data is sent to it. I'm not sure if my `runOnUiThread` is working fine without `removeCallBack` things.

Also do i need `pauseGraphUI()`. I don't know what it is for. 
Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private void postData(final double time, final int pressure) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mCurrentLineGraph.appendData(new DataPoint(time, pressure), false, 1024);
            }
        });
    }

    public void pauseGraphUI() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks((Runnable) mCurrentLineGraph);
     }

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public MainActivity() {
        mHandler = new Handler() { // this the handler
            //private double time = 0.0;

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                byte[] readBuf;
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                        switch (msg.arg1) {
                            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTED: " + msg.arg1);
                                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to,
                                        mConnectedDeviceName));
                                mDigitalInAdapter.clear();
                                startGraph();
                                break;
                            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTING: " + msg.arg1);
                                setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                                break;
                            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                                Log.i(TAG, "STATE_LISTEN | STATE_NONE: " + msg.arg1);
                                setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_WRITE: " + msg.arg1);
                        byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        // construct a string from the buffer
                        String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                        mDigitalInAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_READ://here I'm reading...
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_READ: " + msg.arg1);
                         readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj; // Array that will back the new buffer.
                        // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                        String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(readBuf, 0, readBuf.length);
                        buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
                        Log.i(TAG, "digital read in: " + readMessage + ", str-" + pressure + " s-");

                        String[] strNumbers = readMessage.split("\r"); //stand for ASCII(13);
                        if (strNumbers.length > 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "readMessage = " + readMessage);
                            //  if (strNumbers.length > 0) {
                            //  Log.i(TAG, "digital after split: " + strNumbers[0] + ", length=" + strNumbers.length);
                            // } else {
                            //     Log.i(TAG, "no data read!");
                            //  }

                            readMessage = strNumbers[0];
                            lastInput = strNumbers[0];
                            try {
                                pressure = Integer.valueOf(readMessage);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "NumberFormatException - " + e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (pressure >= 0) {
                                pushDataIntonAdapter("mDigitalInAdapter",mDigitalInAdapter,pressure);

                                float pound;// = 0x0f;
                                try {
                                    pound = digitalToPoundConvert(pressure);
                                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Digital to Pound convert: %04d -> %4.2f", pressure, pound));
                                    pushDataIntonAdapter("mPoundAdapter",mPoundAdapter,pound);
                                    if (mPoundAdapter != null) {
                                        // check if new pounds >= last recorded
                                        if (mRecordingAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
                                            float last_pounds;//= 0.0f;
                                            float current_pounds;// = 0.0f;
                                            last_pounds = Float.parseFloat(mRecordingAdapter.getItem(mRecordingAdapter.getCount() - 1));
                                            current_pounds = Float.parseFloat(mPoundAdapter.getItem(mPoundAdapter.getCount() - 1));

                                            if (current_pounds >= last_pounds) {
                                                // turn data record back on
                                                sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_ALERTDIALOG);
                                            }
                                        }

                                     }
                                    if (mCurrentLineGraph != null) {

                                        postData(time, pressure);
                                        time++;
                                       // pauseGraphUI();

                                        //onResume();
                                       // mCurrentLineGraph.appendData(new DataPoint(time, pressure), false, 1000);
                                        //noinspection NumericOverflow
                                       //time = time + 1.0 /20.0;

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "onProgressUpdate failed: " + e.getMessage());
                                }

                            } else {
                                Log.i(TAG, "The digital was - " + 0);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME: " + msg.arg1);
                        // save the connected device's name
                        mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_TOAST: " + msg.arg1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_ALERTDIALOG:
                        Log.i(TAG,"MESSAGE_ALERTDIALOG"+ msg.arg1);
                        AlerThreshold();

                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```